# Unable to submit a form with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, django

I have a website in Django and I need a form submitted via AJAX to avoid page reloading and perform something in the background. However, I'm unable to do that.

Here's my code for the form:

```
<a href="#" class="trigger">Request a call back</a>
<div class="head hide">No Phone Number on Record</div>
<div class="content hide">

<form method="post" id="phone-form" action="{% url 'customer:profile-update' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" id="id_first_name" maxlength="255" name="first_name"
           value="{% if user.is_authenticated %}{{ user.first_name }}{% endif %}" hidden>
    <input type="text" id="id_last_name" maxlength="255" name="last_name"
           value="{% if user.is_authenticated %}{{ user.last_name }}{% endif %}" hidden>
    <input type="email" id="id_email" maxlength="255" name="email"
           value="{% if user.is_authenticated %}{{ user.email }}{% endif %}" hidden>
    <input type="text" id="id_date_of_birth" maxlength="128" name="date_of_birth"
           value="{% if user.is_authenticated %}{% if user.date_of_birth %}
           {{ user.date_of_birth }}{% endif %}{% endif %}" hidden>
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <label for="id_phone_number">Where do we reach you?</label>
        <input
            id="id_phone_number"
            name="phone_number"
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            placeholder="772734878">
        <div align="center" style="padding-top: 10px;">
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <small>We will add this number to your profile for future communications.</small>
        {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" id="id_update_phone_number" class="btn btn-default btn-block">
        Request a Call
    </button>
</form>

</div>
```

And the code for javascript:

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.ph-in>.trigger').popover({
        html: true,
        placement: 'bottom',
        title: function () {
            return $(this).parent().find('.head').html();
        },
        content: function () {
            return $(this).parent().find('.content').html();
        }
    });

    $('#phone-form').on('submit', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("form submitted!")  // sanity check
    });
});
</script>
```

What could be wrong here? The script for `popover` is working fine and so are the other jQuery related elements - which is to say that the jQuery is loading properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is, that the .content is actually cloned and injected into the DOM inside a , the .popover itself. So the submit() is never binded to the form shown inside the popover, since it is added later. So if we bind the event to document as a delegated event handler, then it will work with the form shown inside .popover too :

```
$(document).on('submit','#id_update_phone_number',function(){
    alert('Form Submitted');
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're preventing the submit intentionally. But you are also missing the call to send the form data using AJAX.

Change you on-submit jQuery call to

```
$('#phone-form').on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax(
       url: {% url 'customer:profile-update' %},
       data: $("#phone-form").serialize() 
       success: function {
          alert("form submitted!")  // sanity check
       }
    );    

});
```

Comment: Yes, currently I just want to see if the call to script is working - which is why I am blocking submit and showing an alert. My idea is that if the alert shows, I can start to implement Ajax code.